# Node.js: XML to String conversion

Tags: node.js

I have `XML` documents shown below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:axlapi="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/10.0">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <axlapi:listDevicePool>
              <searchCriteria>
                <name>%</name>
              </searchCriteria>
               <returnedTags>
                <name/>

              </returnedTags>
        </axlapi:listDevicePool>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here I want to convert this `XML` to `string`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also you do realise that XML is actually string, right? You need to be more specific and show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) module to easily convert the XML to a JavaScript object and then do what you want with it.

Example:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "YOUR XML";
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

Do you have that XML in the string? In a file? As a response to a web request? If it's not in a string then you will have to load it first.